# How to define scheme and target of xcode in premake5 config

Tags: xcode, premake

There is a xcode project, with two scheme and two build target. How should I to config the scheme and target in premake5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Premake currently does not support creating custom schemes. Pull requests are always welcome! Keep in mind that the purpose of Premake is to generate builds that work across a variety of tool sets. Schemes are Xcode specific, and don't easily translate to the project models used by other tools.